# Нужен ли предлог "в"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Он не может вспомнить, когда (в) последний раз говорил.

Читаю сейчас книгу в переводе с английского. Уже несколько раз попадались предложения, где перед "прошлый", "последний" нет "в". Хотя по смыслу, мне кажется, должно быть.

Answer (score 1):

***Он не может вспомнить, когда в последний раз говорил (с кем-то).***

**Пояснение**

Есть два варианта, когда мы определяем:

1) **Который по счету раз** что-то происходит (первый, второй... последний). *Это случилось первый раз. Первый раз в первый класс.*

2) **О котором случае из ряда подобных** идет речь. *В первый раз дорога показалась длинной, во второй раз она уже казалась короче. В последний раз (при встрече) мы уже всё это обсуждали, зачем повторять заново.*

3) В приведенном примере персонаж пытается вспомнить дату последнего разговора, но не подробности того, чтобы было в тот раз.

Сравнить: ***Последний раз*** мы встречались с ним перед Новым годом. Не могу вспомнить, о чем мы говорили с ним **в последний раз.**

[http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=раз&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7&all=x)

Answer (score 0):

В данном - наречном сочетании допустимы оба варианта.

Answer (score 0):

Касательно слова "последний": смысл тот же, но есть одна огромная разница в интерпретации этого смысла, которая не является очевидной на первый взгляд, но может ощущаться русскоговорящим человеком. А именно эта особенность: [https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/17370/Какая-разница-между-словосочетаниями-в-последний-раз-и-последний-раз](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/17370/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7)

Именно по этой причине в грамотной речи нельзя использовать предлог "в" вместе с данным словом в позитивном аспекте, что и подтверждает ваша книга, так как книги являются образцом грамотности.

Со словосочетанием "в прошлый раз" никаких проблем нет, но возможно, что в этой книге слово "прошлый" также принято использовать без предлога, чтобы оно совпадало с использованием слова "последний". Хотя здесь лучше рассматривать конкретные примеры.